# .net search for string between two known strings in a file

Tags: .net, regex, string, file, search

I have a big text file. Lots of irrelevant data in it. I can read it into StreamReader and doing a while loop. My text file is like this

***MyStartString***
     "response:"My response from web service1
**MyEndString
somedata in between
***MyStartString***
"response:"My response from web service2
**MyEndString

So its going to be like this (around 70MB file). I need to retrieve the "response:"My response from web service1 and "response:"My response from web service2 etc into a list. I saw that we can do this with Regex. Can someone help me out. I saw a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781304/extracting-specific-part-of-a-text-file-in-c-sharp) on this.

UPDATE: I am pasting below my file extract. So, you can see "****MgrType Response Body**" and "**End::" below. There is a response between them. I need to get those responses. Image file[image: Regex correct matched with 2 matches]

My File Extract :

employeetype: manager

**MgrType Request Payload**
{"events":[{"some data"}]}}}}]}

****Nfn Response Header**

X-Original-HTTP-Status-Code: 200

MyID: cc24e044-babf-46d3-bda5-bb0de1e586e5

Connection: close

Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2016 21:28:01 GMT

***MgrType Response Body**

{"response":{" SOME DATA 1 \n---  END MESSAGES  ---\n"}]}}}

**End::Event 1  out of 1**

*** Done with  Nfn  to xyzserver***

SOMEDATA HERE1

SOMEDATA HERE2

SOMEDATA HERE3

SOMEDATA HERE4

...

SOMEDATA HERE555

***MgrType Response Body**

{"response":{" SOME DATA 2\n---  END MESSAGES  ---\n"}]}}}

**End::Event 1  out of 1**

*** Done with  Nfn  to xyzserver***

Comment: You will need to specify the format of your file more precisely. Does it have multiple lines? Where can the initiator and terminator strings appear in the file (or lines)?

Comment: @AttilaRepasi. I have added the file extract.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Match and in the pattern search for any character between your start and end strings.If its a match,add to the list.

```
string s;
List<string> sList = new List<string>();

using(StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader("Text1.text"))
{
     while((s = oReader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         sList.Add(Regex.Match(s, @"MyStartString(.+?)MyEndString").Groups[1].Value);
     }
}
foreach(string s in sList)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Your expression will select spaces and asteriks. I suggest this one `(?<=MyStartString)(?:[\s\*]*)(.+?)(?:[\s\*]*)(?=MyEndString)`. Also, the global modifier should be used if several matches per line are possible.

Comment: @Niitaku, I tried both the techniques and get a list of empty strings i.e. "" (count of 51). Here is what put : sList.Add(Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=Body)(?:[\s\*]*)(.+?)(?:[\s\*]*)(?=End::)/g").Groups[1].Value); I tried using "/g" and it matched correctly in https://regex101.com/. But not here.Please see attached image.